# parse php code snippet as a string to get the value of a particular variable

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

I have a varchar field in my db which contains :

```
 "<?php     
     $html = 'abc' ;    
     $ad_content = Agencies_anonymous::getAd($html);    
     echo $ad_content;
  ?>"
```

Now , in my code, I have to read this field value and get the value of the variable **$html**

.What would be the apt way to do this ?

Supposedly , I have extracted the field value as a string(*$html_string*) in my code .

What will be the appropiate regular expression that I should apply for this ? Or , is there any robust method using string functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using php to do this? Does the statement always look exactly like this?

```
$code.split("'")[1]
```

would get it
or

```
$codeSegs = $code.split(' ');
foreach($i = 0; $i <  $codeSegs.length; $i++)
 if ($codeSegs[$i] == "$html")
   return $codeSeg[$i+2].split("'")[1];
```

Comment: thanks @thanktos ...that was really good effort on your part.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a varchar field in my db which contains :

The best thing you can do is to have NO such a varchar field with no such a content.

Keep your code separated from data and you will escape great number of mistakes and disasters.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to interpret php code from within php code, you have to use the [eval() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Javascript also has something similar.

```
$var = "
    $html = 'abc' ;    
    $ad_content = Agencies_anonymous::getAd($html);    
    echo $ad_content;
"

eval($var);
// $html should now be 'in-scope' for usage...
```